# What information does the four vector of momentum dotted with itself give us?

Tags: special-relativity

For example the dot product of the four vector, momentum, of a photon with itself is zero, is this simply telling us the particle is light-like or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot product of the four-momentum with itself is the mass of the particle. In special relativity you can show the following:

$$p^\mu = \left(\begin{array}{c}E/c \\ \vec p \end{array}\right) \qquad E = \gamma mc^2 \qquad \vec p = \gamma m \vec v$$

Computing $p^\mu p_\mu$ gives

$$ p^\mu p_\mu = E^2/c^2 - |\vec p|^2 = (mc)^2\gamma^2\left(1 - \frac{|\vec v|^2}{c^2}\right) = m^2c^2$$

As you correctly said, the dot product of the four-momentum of a photon with itself is zero, because the photon has zero mass.